# Able to update dataset but unable to commit changes to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm experiencing some troubles with trying to update the Database from a dataset.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server 2016, and creating a WFA.

I'm creating a simple CRUD application, but when I try to add a new record, or update a current one, the dataset get's updated, but not the actual database.
I've literary spend hours going through my code (even though it's only about 350 LOC) and I couldn't find the problem. And when I use a break at the insert this is the query I can retrieve:

```
    --The data may be truncated and may not represent the query that was run on the server
--Database name is unknown.

--Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.
DECLARE @p1 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p2 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p3 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p4 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p5 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p1 = NULL;
SET @p2 = NULL;
SET @p3 = NULL;
SET @p4 = NULL;
SET @p5 = NULL;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Players] ([player_name], [player_surname], [player_fine], [player_team_id], [player_position_id]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)
```

Any idea's why it stays empty, because I haven't got a clue what so ever, it seems to me it should work because the dataset remembers the data, and I'm only trying to update the database from the dataset.

This is the part of the code from my database connection class which should update the database:

```
        public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_0);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
```

And here is the part that updates the dataset:

```
private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Doub = convertToDouble(textBox_Fined);
    IntCBTeam = convertToInt(textBox_TeamId);
    IntCBPosition = convertToInt(textBox_PositionId);


    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

    row[1] = textBox_FirstName.Text;
    row[2] = textBox_Surname.Text;
    row[3] = Doub;
    row[4] = IntCBTeam;
    row[5] = IntCBPosition;

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

    try
    {
        DBAccess.UpdateDatabase(ds);
        MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
        inc = MaxRows - 1;

        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully saved record");


    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

    }

    button_Cancel.Enabled = false;
    button_Save.Enabled = false;
    button_New.Enabled = true;
}
```

Pressing the save button replies with the `Messagebox.Show("Succesfully saved record")` Which leads me to believe that the connection with the database is okay, but I might be wrong. This is where I lack experience sadly.
Hopefully one of you guys can spot my mistake.

Please, do ask me for further information which I unintentionally left out if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was the automatically generated connection string in the properties settings. I had to replace the "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DBOne.mdf" `[DataDirectory]` with the actual location "`C:\...\DBOne.mdf`" to make it work.